# $.ajax() success won't run,everytime it runs the error

Tags: ajax

$.ajax() success won't run,everytime it runs the error function.i don't know why its happening.

my code is---

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/mod/basket.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ({ id : item[0], job : item[1] }),
            success: function(data) {
                var new_id = item[0] + '_' + data.job;
                if (data.job != item[1]) {
                    if (data.job == 0) {
                        trigger.attr("rel", new_id);
                        trigger.text("Remove from basket");
                        trigger.addClass("red");
                    } else {
                        trigger.attr("rel", new_id);
                        trigger.text("Add to basket");
                        trigger.removeClass("red");
                    }
                    refreshSmallBasket();
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("An error has occurred");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you have an error as well in your console of chrome / firebug?

Comment: What's the error that comes back from the server?

Comment: Did you notice the error callback receive arguments ?

Comment: console of chrome--
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/ecommerce/basket.php   Stefan

Comment: The console will show the AJAX post and the result of it.

Comment: i fix the console error. now no  error is showing in my console.but nothing happens to my problem.it's altime goes to the error function

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted enough debugging information for us to get to the root of your problem.

However, the `error` callback on `$.ajax` is passed three parameters on execution, if you replace your current error callback with this one you should get to the root of the problem in no time:

```
function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.error('AJAX request responded with error code:', textStatus, 'The error:', errorThrown, 'was thrown.')
}
```

Execute your AJAX again with this error callback and check your console.